# Night Light turns screen green

Tags: display, screen

[Green screen when Night Light on](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mq9IQ.gif)

I have two displays. Main monitor through DVI works normal with Night Light. When I change to the HDMI display which is a OLED TV the image is ok except when I activate Night Light. The image turns green!

I've looked everywhere for this issue but couldn't find any solution. I've messed with the nvidia settings but with no success. Another issue is when I click Mirror Display it crashes and doesn't do anything. I've uploaded screenshots for better understanding.
[Mirror Display crashes](https://i.stack.imgur.com/eNif1.png)
[nvidia driver](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gvPBQ.png)
[nvidia settings](https://i.stack.imgur.com/y0Ivu.png)
[nvidia settings2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FcHzj.png)

Ubuntu 19.10 nvidia drivers 435 (tested 440 same result)

Comment: I have the same problem on a Samsung LS03R QLED Frame. Night light comes on and screen turns green. Very irritating. I don't know if it's an Ubuntu problem or a Samsung problem.

Answer (score 5):

Finally discovered the real fix for this on the Redshift github.

Solution is to add this line in the "Device" section of xorg.conf

```
Option "UseNvKmsCompositionPipeline" "false"
```

Details here: https://github.com/jonls/redshift/issues/720

Comment: [ArchWiki for Redshift](https://wiki.archlinux.org/title/redshift#Redshift_turns_the_screen_green_when_resolution_is_over_1080p_while_using_Nvidia_drivers) also has an example for the modern `xorg.conf.d`.

Comment: On Arch+GNOME, I tried my comment but was stuck with a black screen on startup. Had to revert the change in an install medium to recover. Be careful!